# Facebook says vanity URL for page is not available, but it is not used by another page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I'm trying to claim a short URL "`www.facebook.com/[URLGOESHERE]`" for my FB community page. I'm doing this at https://www.facebook.com/username but when I do so it says "[URLGOESHERE] is not available". This is despite the fact there's nothing at `https://www.facebook.com/[URLGOESHERE]`. Help, anyone?

Comment: There's a possibility you entered the wrong URL.

Comment: Are you using any "special" characters, other than the usual a-z etc.?

Comment: @w3d: No, just letters.

Comment: @user79626 I didn't enter the wrong URL.

Comment: I seem to recall that a page needed to have a minimum number of "Likes" before you could get a vanity URL for it. I don't know if that's still true. It might also be that the vanity URL you want has been used in the past and, even though there is no page there now, Fbook won't let you recycle it.

Comment: @AlE. that's helpful, though I can't find it documented anywhere - do you have *any* idea what the minimum number is?

Comment: [This seems to suggest](https://www.facebook.com/help/211337555567785) that a page name can be taken but if it is left as  unpublished then you'll get the above message

Comment: I misremembered. You used to need 25 Likes, but that restriction was removed some time ago. ([source](http://allfacebook.com/you-no-longer-need-25-fans-to-get-a-custom-page-url_b58421))

Comment: @AlE. I think it may have come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you need to get a minimum of 25 likes first. Another reason for this message can be that certain words (like 'facebook') are restricted, or that the username was reserved by an earlier page that's no longer up. For more, see also https://www.facebook.com/help/211337555567785

Comment: Like counts doesn't matter for page username. And _or that the username was reserved by an earlier page that's no longer up_ is the same thing what _@phwd_ has written in his [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/68990/87130) in easy language.

Answer (score 5):

A possible scenario is that the username was taken at one point and then the page was deleted / username changed of the page. This makes the username unavailable for an unspecified period of time.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. Indeed now that I try it *any* username I try says 'notavailable', which wasn't the case just 2 days ago when I named another FB page. Here are some I tried (as pure made up tests), LMK if they work for you: 'allory', 'aperception', 'neuroperception', 'paigeatkinson'.